# Perform UNION ALL on multiple CTE iteratively , without wirting the name of each CTE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, common-table-expression

The code bellow works fine, but there is a real possibility that more CTEs will be added in the future. I know I have to define them in the `with` clause, but can I cheat and add them with a `for` loop of some sort to the `UNION ALL` ?

```
with
cte_1 as (select 1 as c1),
cte_2 as (select 1 as c1),
cte_3 as (select 1 as c1)

select * from cte_1
UNION ALL
select * from cte_2
UNION ALL
select * from cte_3
```

Comment: Cheat no, dynamic sql yes

Comment: you can load several tables with `Select * from yourdataset.yourtable_cte_*` But this does not work with temporary tables or CTEs. With the tool "DBT" you can generate SQL code.

Comment: can you clarify what is your real use case - it is not clear why you would want to do that. please provide more details on use case